# What's the rectangle surrounding a font glyph, including its sidebearings, called?

Tags: typography, terminology, font-design

What's the rectangle surrounding a font glyph, including its sidebearings, called? I Googled the words "bounding box" and got conflicting results, where [some sources](https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-3.html) say it's the rectangle that bound the glyph tightly (without sidebearings), and [others](https://superluminal.eu/16x-aa-font-rendering-using-coverage-masks-part-iii/) say it includes sidebearings.

[image]

Comment: Not everything has a name unfortunately. There may in fact be no name, or multiple names for this.

Comment: @joojaa After hours of futile research, even going so far as looking into non-English sources, I reluctantly agree.

Comment: In German it's "Schriftkegel"

Comment: @JulianSteinmann you should convert that to an answer. THough ists not exactly the same thing, but close enough

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that this does not have an official, authoritative name. There is certainly no need for this name in the font specification because this is a calculated value, not really needed for anything in the font drawing.

You're in luck! You can make the authoritative name.

Comment: I talked to a font designer and he said that it does not have a name but if it does its M size

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after doing quite a bit of research, here's my conclusion: there seems to be no perfect English term. But there is one workable candidate, although it won't be very useful in English: "body". This is a reference to the "body" of a [sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(typesetting)) in movable typesetting, [as suggested by user K Pease on Typedrawers](https://typedrawers.com/discussion/4468/whats-the-rectangle-surrounding-a-font-glyph-including-its-sidebearings-called#latest). It is in fact still used in Japanese type design, specifically as [仮想ボディ](http://zokeifile.musabi.ac.jp/%E4%BB%AE%E6%83%B3%E3%83%9C%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3/) ("imaginary body"), given that "bodies" are much more important as a concept in East Asian calligraphy and typography than Western ones. ["Imaginary body"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mo0TXNAQ290), although a literal translation, is indeed used in some very limited English materials translated from Japanese, so it's not completely terrible. Adobe translates this term as ["embox"](https://helpx.adobe.com/ee/indesign/using/formatting-cjk-characters.html), which can be confused with the concept of the ["em square"](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/The_EM_Square.html), but given that the height of this box is always exactly one em, it's not a bad one either. The only problems with "imaginary body" and "embox" is that I haven't found any concrete demonstration of these terms on Western text in Japanese sources (most examples are strictly about Japanese text), but I hazard it wouldn't be that different anyway.

In short, "body", "imaginary body" or "embox". Not perfect, but still usable to some extent.